# c++ thread waiting for user IO ('getchar()') hangs 'Py_Initialize()' in main process

Tags: c++, python, multithreading

I just stumbled upon a really strange problem.  In my code, I have one thread launch to wait for user input---in case the user wants to interrupt the main process.  After that thread is going, I try to do some computations using python.  The thread looks for user input using `getchar()` -- if the input is a return, a boolean flag is set to make the main process stop doing what its doing.  The main process checks this flag every once and a while, and if its set, it takes appropriate action.

Schematically:

```
bool volatile stopper = false;
thread stopThread(interrupt, &stopper);
while( !stopper ) {
    /* ... stuff ... */
    Py_Initialize();                            // this doesn't return unless 'interrupt()' completes.
    /* ... do things with python object ... */
}
```

the interrupt method looks like,

```
void interrupt(bool *st) {
    char ch;   
    while( ch != '\n' ) {
        ch = getchar();
    }
    *st = true;
}
```

If I replace the `getchar()` while-loop with a `sleep(10)`, the `Py_Initialize()` returns fine, and everything works great.  Why is the IO request blocking `Py_Initialize()`?

thanks!

Comment: Probably unrelated, but in theory you need to declare the "stopper" variable with `bool volatile stopper = false;`.  Otherwise the C++ compiler has the right to consider that the `while(!stopper) { }` loop is an infinite loop, if no code in the loop can change the value of `stopper` (i.e. if it can only be changed from another thread in parallel).

Comment: @MatsPetersson, I said taking out `getChar()` makes it work.

Comment: So what does getChar() do? I take it is different from getchar()?

Comment: Nope, sorry, definitely just `getchar()` --- my mistake

Comment: @ArminRigo that's an interesting point, I wasn't aware of `volatile`.  Thanks.

Comment: did you try swapping the work of both threads, and calling getchar() on the main thread, while initializing on the other thread? IO Input might be restricted to your main thread

Comment: @cppanda, I like the idea -- but the `getchar()` does work fine --- if i hit `RETURN` (and the thread ends), then `Py_Initialize()` works, and the program exits as it should.

Answer (score 1):

When you call an I/O function like `getchar`, you hold a lock on some I/O object until the function terminates. It is very bad form to hold a lock indefinitely in a multi-threaded program, as that will cause any thread that tries to acquire that lock to block indefinitely. Don't call blocking I/O functions in multi-threaded programs.